# pandas filter with replace and search

Tags: pandas, replace, filter

I have such dataframe

I want to fitler rows and replace values based on the filter. I want to apply two different operations based on the replacement value.

How to do this as my current approach does not work.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': ['aa', 'bb', 'c banana a dupa'], 'b': ['\w','\d','[ab-c]','[^c b]']})

df['filter'] = (df['a'] > 2).replace({True: f"dupa {df['b']}", False: re.search(df['b'], df['a'])})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), because `replace` is used for replacement by scalars, then for compare lengths use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html), for prepend value only `+` and for search use `apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': ['aa', 'bb', 'c banana a dupa', 'dd'], 
                        'b': ['\w','\d','[ab-c]','[^c b]']})

df['filter'] = np.where(df['a'].str.len() > 2, 
                        "dupa " + df['b'],  
                        df.apply(lambda x: re.search(x['b'], x['a']), axis=1))
print (df)

                 a       b                                     filter
0               aa      \w  <re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
1               bb      \d                                       None
2  c banana a dupa  [ab-c]                                dupa [ab-c]
3               dd  [^c b]  <re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='d'>
```